# Horizontal image view with image preview in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to set images horizontally.I tried using list box it is scrolling vertically even ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" is there any way to set images or any control to use?,Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `ItemPanelTemplate` first, try this

```XAML
<ListBox x:Name="myLLS" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <!-- here is where we change stuff -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                <StackPanel Height="100" Background="#FF00044D">
                    <!-- Your Image collection from your ViewModel -->
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>                    
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```